# How to prevent python workers from crashing when all database connections from connection pool are already used by other workers

Tags: python, mysql, multiprocessing, connection-pooling

We have python workers that process images and autoscale based on the queue size. Each worker needs to connect to the DB. We are using the smallest Amazon RDS instance which allows ~50 or so concurrent DB connections. At one point we faced mysql "Too many connections" error and our developer implemented connection pool which at the time seemed to solve the problem. However, later we decided to see if we can scale the workers based on their idle status (is the worker alive, is it processing something or is it idle) and decided to register each worker in DB and record their status. After this we started running into the "Too many connections" connections again.

Question: When a connection pool is created with, for example 10 max connection limit, I understand that all those connections are being reused. What happens when all the 10 connections are busy and more workers try to connect. How to prevent the py worker from crashing and make sure that it waits for the connections to open up?

Comment: Your connection pool implementation isn't shown. Maybe a worker could disconnect when it is processing a job. If this doesn't solve the lack of resources maybe there are slow queries. Are you starting more workers than connections? How are workers waiting - surely they can catch and exception. Alternately, queue based workloads probably should be using a message queue like RabbitMQ rather than a SQL database.

Comment: Yes, what happens in the case when there are more workers than the available resources -  the unused connections in the connection pool? We are currently using Rabbit MQ but as I understand everything boils down to the connection pool max connection limit, and what happens when all connections are used. Does the connection pool have a built in mechanism to delay the connection from the other workers?

Comment: Hi @danblack , I just wanted to check in if my question makes sense?

Comment: Not to me. Not enough details. Hope someone else is interested in guessing for you.

Comment: I am sorry @danblack but what do you mean with guessing. When all available connections in the connection pool are being used by some workers and we create even more workers, how to prevent those new workers from crashing because they can't connect to the DB? How does connection pool handle that? I don't know how else to rephrase the question. Yes, we are starting more workers than connections in the pool.

Comment: Is there anyone who knows the answer to "What happens when all the 10 connections are busy and more workers try to connect?"